# K time differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Is there any k time differentiable function such that $$f(f'(f''(f'''(......f^{(k)}(x))))=x$$ for all $x$ belongs to $\mathbb R$?

EDIT:- What will the case be when the order of the functions taken are reversed?

Comment: I would start with the $k=1$ case.  If we assume a second derivative can be taken, we get $f'(f'(x))f''(x)=1$ and defining $g(x)=f'(x)$ we get $g(g(x))g'(x)=1$.  I don't know if that helps.

Comment: sorry i could not get you

Comment: I would take $k = 0$ and $f(x) = x$... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such $f$.

Let $J$ be the range of $f' \circ f'' \circ \ldots \circ f^{(k)}$, which is an interval.  Then $f$ must be injective on $J$ and maps it to $\mathbb R$.  But we can't have 
$f(x) \to \pm \infty$ as $x$ approaches any point of $J$ or its closure, because then $f^{(k)}$ wouldn't be defined there.  So $J$ must be the whole real line.
But if $f$ is differentiable and injective on $\mathbb R$, it is either increasing or decreasing, so either $f' \ge 0$ everywhere or $f' \le 0$ everywhere.  But then
$J$ is contained in either $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, 0]$, contradiction!

EDIT: Similarly, consider the order-reversed problem
$$ f^{(k)}(\ldots(f'(f(x)))\ldots) = x$$

Let $J$ be the range of $f^{(k-1)} \circ \ldots \circ f$, again an interval $J$,
which $f^{(k)}$ must map one-to-one onto $\mathbb R$.  Again, this should imply that $J$ is all of $\mathbb R$.  The same agument then implies that the range of
$f^{(k-2)} \circ \ldots \circ f$ is all of $\mathbb R$, and $f^(k-1)$ is one-to-one.  But that would require $f^{(k)}$ to be always $\ge 0$ or always $\le 0$.

Comment: can you explain to me , how are you getting J be the whole real axis?

Comment: Somehow $f(x)$ must have values in $J$ that approach $+\infty$, and values in $J$ that approach $-\infty$.  Take a sequence $x_n$ in $J$ such that $f(x_n) \to +\infty$.  $x_n$ can't have any finite limit point $L$ because $f$ must be continuous at $L$, so the only option is that $|x_n| \to \infty$.  Similarly for a sequence $y_n$ with $f(y_n) \to -\infty$.  But since $f$ is injective on $J$ you can't have subsequences of both $x_n$ and $y_n$ going to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$:
the only possibility is $x_n \to+\infty$ and $y_n \to -\infty$ or vice versa.  But then $J$ must be all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Very interesting @RobertIsrael! What happens if we restrict the domain in which $f\circ f'\circ f'' \circ \cdots f^{(k)} (x) = x$? For example, take $$f(x) = Kx^\alpha.$$ then $$f'(x)=K\alpha x ^{\alpha-1}$$ and $$f(f'(x)) = K^{\alpha+1} \alpha^{\alpha} x^{\alpha^2-\alpha}.$$ If we let $f(f'(x)) = x$ for all $x$ in the domain of the function, we get $$\alpha=\phi$$ and $$K= \phi^{-\frac{\phi}{\phi+1}},$$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this works for $x > 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, yes that's what I meant. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @RobertIsrael suppose now to take $$f(x)=\begin{cases} \phi^{-\frac{\phi}{\phi+1}} x^\phi & (x >0)\\ 0 & (x=0) \\ -\phi^{-\frac{\phi}{\phi+1}} (-x)^\phi & (x <0)\end{cases}$$ Does not this function satisfy the OP requirement for $k=1$?

Comment: Oops, no. That gives $f(f'(x)) = |x|$.

Comment: okay thanks for explaining to me